# Flutter doctor android-studio-dir problem

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

When I run flutter doctor, it renders these 2 errors and I can't find a way to get over them:

```
C:\Users\Work pc>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.5, on Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.19041.928], locale fr-CH)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    X Cannot execute C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe to determine the version
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[!] Android Studio
    X android-studio-dir = C:\Program
    X Android Studio not found at C:\Program
[√] VS Code (version 1.55.2)
[√] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

I mainly have difficulties with solving the second problem, related to android studio.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

try running this command on your terminal `flutter config --android-studio-dir=[path/to/android-studio]`

Comment: Thank you ! I managed to solve the issue by resetting the android-studio-dir location. Someone explained on another question that I "corrupted the path tree" by adding whitespaces in the command line on a previous attempt. So to reset it, I typed flutter config --android-studio-dir="". I restarted my computer and that basically solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command in your cmd

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir=""
```

Then restart all your editors for them to load new settings